# How to extract minimal set of options from pyecharts object?

Tags: python, html, plot, echarts

I have used the great pyecharts library to create a rather complicated plot in python. The final goal is to serve through an API the plot, so I need to extract the options that I can pass to echarts to render the plots.

The whole plot is built with a Tab object, and each tab holds a Grid. The problem is that Tab does not have a `dump_options` method (as Grid and single plots do).

Plus, I would like to keep only the minimal set of options needed to create the plot, in a similar way as the [echarts examples](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=dataset-simple0), where many of the "basics" are handled by echarts directly.

The best I can think of is to extract from the HTML file the code, but I would like to get only the minimal set of options